# How to get single digit in a integer in Scheme

Tags: scheme

hi I am a scheme beginner, have an assignment that need to determine leapy year. But i noticed there is no use of (/ 1992 100) to get 19 like C. And there is also no % operator to get a reminder.thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
guile> (quotient 1992 100)
19
guile> (modulo 1992 100)
92
```

from http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/r4rs/r4rs_8.html